# Insert string from <script> into to <a href="">

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have the following script:

```
<script>var b=document;var c=varName;b.write(c);</script>
```

and I want to pass the value from the `<script>` tag to the `name` URL parameter in a link, in place of the `*` here:

```
`<a href="whatsapp://send?text='Hello This is My Demo Site. Visit http://example.com/ex.html?name=ABC*'"> WhatsApp </a>`
```

My attempt resulted in getting the whole script string:

`<a href="whatsapp://send?text='Hello This is My Demo Site. Visit http://example.com/ex.html?name=ABC<script>var b=document;var c=varName;b.write(c);</script>'"> WhatsApp </a>`

Comment: Apologies, but this is completely unclear. Perhaps you could have a friend or colleague help with the English.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot insert scripts within an HTML attribute. You must compose the complete HTML first:

```
<a id="caption" href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello This is My Demo Site. Visit http://example.com/ex.html">link text</a>
```

... And then, you can modify it from javascript:

```
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById("caption");
    var question = "%3F";
    var equal = "%3D";
    a.href += question + "name" + equal + "ABC" + lusername;
</script>
```

Note that I did intentionally escape "?" and "=" when forming the parameters, because I understand they are arguments for the `http://www.example.com` URL and not for the `whatsapp://send` URL.

Comment: You are really awesome :) Nice Understanding. I am sorry for my bad English but you got me. Accepted :)

Comment: @PratikButani Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `varName` is known when the page loads, and is set in a `script` tag earlier in the HTML than where you want the link, then you can just output the entire link with script:

```
<script>
document.write(
    '<a href="whatsapp://send?text=\'Hello This is My Demo Site. Visit http://example.com/ex.html%3Fname%3DABC' +
    varName + '\'"> WhatsApp </a>'
);
</script>
```

If `varName` is dynamic, then you'll want to do something like [Little Santi showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294020/157247) each time you change it. See also his/her point about encoding the `?` and `=` on the `example.com` link text, which I've applied above.